# SQL: count rows where column = a value AND another column is the same as values in the group where the first condition is true?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, group-by, count

I need to count the number of rows for each employee where the `status = 9` and the `date` is the same as other rows within that `employee_id` where the `status = 9`.  I also want the `employee_id` and `count_all`, a count of all the rows for each employee.

Figuring out how to get the `count_same_date_status_9` column is where I am stuck.  These dates are made up just for the example so I dont want to put them explicitly into the query.

My table:

```
employee_id     status     date
1               9          10/19/2020
1               7          07/16/2001
1               9          10/19/2020
2               5          08/11/2011
2               9          12/25/2012
2               9          11/19/2013
3               5          06/05/2016
3               4          01/01/2021
4               9          02/15/2018
4               9          02/15/2018
4               9          02/15/2018
```

I want to return the following:

```
employee_id     count_same_date_status_9     count_all
1               2                            3
2               0                            3
3               0                            2
4               3                            3
```

Comment: And if there are two status = 9 with same date, but one with another date?

Comment: then count the ones with the same date but not the one with a unique date

Comment: Why do you expect *zero* if there is *one* record with the `type = 9` per date?

Comment: im only interested in the `status = 9`s with the same date for each employee.  That date doesnt have to be the same across all employees however.

Comment: To clarify again: So employee #2 has two `status` that equal `9` but the dates for those rows dont match, so therefore the `count_same_date_status_9` must equal `0`.  I only care if the dates match the dates within each employee though, not the dates under the other employees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT employee_id,
       MAX( CASE WHEN status = 9 AND cnt > 1 THEN cnt ELSE 0 END ) AS count_9,
       SUM( cnt ) AS count_all
FROM   (
  SELECT employee_id,
         status,
         dt,
         COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM   table_name
  GROUP BY employee_id, status, dt
)
GROUP BY employee_id
ORDER BY employee_id;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( employee_id, status, dt ) AS
SELECT 1, 9, DATE '2020-10-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 7, DATE '2001-07-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 9, DATE '2020-10-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 5, DATE '2011-08-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 9, DATE '2012-12-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 9, DATE '2013-11-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 5, DATE '2016-06-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 9, DATE '2018-02-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 9, DATE '2018-02-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 9, DATE '2018-02-15' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> EMPLOYEE_ID | COUNT_9 | COUNT_ALL
> ----------: | ------: | --------:
>           1 |       2 |         3
>           2 |       0 |         3
>           3 |       0 |         2
>           4 |       3 |         3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=382b89cc34a1450bf266cc9776298a56)*

Answer (score 1):

The logic you want is a bit counter-intuitive, but I think you can do this with two levels of aggregation:

```
select employee_id,
    case when max(cnt2) = 1 then 0 else max(cnt2) end count_same_date_status_9,
    sum(cnt1) count_all
from (
    select employee_id, dt, count(*) cnt1, sum(case when status = 9 then 1 else 0 end) cnt2
    from mytable t
    group by employee_id, dt
) t
group by employee_id
order by employee_id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=174548695e518d4d60c56f88f8670471)**:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID | COUNT_SAME_DATE_STATUS_9 | COUNT_ALL
----------: | -----------------------: | --------:
          1 |                        2 |         3
          2 |                        0 |         3
          3 |                        0 |         2
          4 |                        3 |         3
```

Comment: this didnt work for me.  I think theres a typo because i get `"CNT": invalid identifier`

Comment: @JacobMyer: I did not copy/paste the last version of the query (while it was OK in the fiddle). Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The result can be achieved with a simple group by, then a subquery to find the most `status = 9` that occured on the same day.

#### Query

```sql
WITH
    employees (employee_id, status, status_date)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 9, TO_DATE ('10/19/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 7, TO_DATE ('07/16/2001', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 9, TO_DATE ('10/19/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 5, TO_DATE ('08/11/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 9, TO_DATE ('12/25/2012', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 9, TO_DATE ('11/19/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 5, TO_DATE ('06/05/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 4, TO_DATE ('01/01/2021', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 9, TO_DATE ('02/15/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 9, TO_DATE ('02/15/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 9, TO_DATE ('02/15/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM DUAL)
  SELECT employee_id,
         NVL ((SELECT MAX (count_9)
                 FROM (  SELECT employee_id, status_date, COUNT (*) AS count_9
                           FROM employees e2
                          WHERE e2.status = 9 AND e2.employee_id = o.employee_id
                       GROUP BY employee_id, status_date)
               HAVING MAX (count_9) > 1),
              0)    AS count_same_date_status_9,
         count_all
    FROM (  SELECT employee_id, COUNT (*) AS count_all
              FROM employees e1
          GROUP BY employee_id) o
ORDER BY employee_id
```

#### Result

```sql
   EMPLOYEE_ID    COUNT_SAME_DATE_STATUS_9    COUNT_ALL
______________ ___________________________ ____________
             1                           2            3
             2                           0            3
             3                           0            2
             4                           3            3
```

Answer (score 0):

this might work for MSSQL;

```
    select employee_id,sum(A),sum(B) from(
    select employee_id,count(*) A ,0 B from TABLENAME group by employee_id,status
    union all
    select employee_id,0 A,count(*) B from TABLENAME group by employee_id,date
    ) C group by employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone gave this answer then deleted it so I'm not sure who to give credit to, but this query seems to be working as intended and is pretty simple to read:

```
select employee_id, sum(case when status = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as count_same_date_status_9, count(*) as count_all
from table_name
group by employee_id;
```

Comment: It was me, but I deleted it since it will not work with different status 9 dates.